# Return data in xml or json format in asp.net 5 web api 2 according to request header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr

I am developing web api using asp.net web api 2, MVC 6 and asp.net 5 i.e. dnxcore50 (core clr).

My requirement is to return data in in xml or json format as required in request header. If header has Accept type set to application/xml or application/xhtml+xml my api endpoint should return requested data in xml format. Also same for json format as well if header has Accept type set to  application/json, my api endpoint should return data in json format.

I have tried using following code in startup but with no success.

In ConfigureServices() method I have following code:

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.InputFormatters.Add( new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add( new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });
```

Can anyone guide me what am I missing here or what is wrongly configured.

Comment: You're missing the code you need to write that reads the request header and formats the response data to the requested format.

Comment: What code am I missing and where is that to be written? code should be at application level as I can not afford to write for each controller action method.